# Umbraco upgrade throwing Creative Web Starter errors

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, umbraco, upgrade

It seems that CWS isn't really supported past umbraco v4.7.2. I have a problem now where most of our websites (50+) use CWS data types to hold contents.

Basically when I go from 4.7.2 to 4.8, I get this in debug..  I think it's going to be a rough journey to version 6.

The exception was System.Exception and the message was Unable to load one or more of the types in assembly 'Creative.Website.Starter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exceptions were thrown:
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'RenderJsDependencies' in type 'Creative.Website.Starter.ClientDependency.Html5StandardRenderer' from assembly 'Creative.Website.Starter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation..    at umbraco.BusinessLogic.Utils.TypeFinder.FindClassesMarkedWithAttribute(Assembly assembly, Type attribute)
  at umbraco.BusinessLogic.Utils.TypeFinder.FindClassesMarkedWithAttribute(Type attribute)
  at umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, Object& result)

And I assume this means CWS is no longer supported and i'm out of luck.

Questions:
- Is there any way to migrate CWS field contents to normal text data types so I can uninstall CWS and upgrade?

- Or has anyone been able to use CWS packages in umbraco v4.7.2 + version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Scary but just delete the Creative.Website.Starter.dll from the bin folder to fix the error but I think your out of luck with the whole CWS issue in version 6x!

Comment: yep, deleting the Creative.Website.Starter.dll  from bin folder in file explorer helped